# Ajax call to Instagram (GET /media/search) timestamp issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I'm Getting `400 bad request` as a response:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APIInvalidParametersError","code":400,"error_message":"invalid parameters-check the max\/min-timestamps, if you supplied them"}}
```

while my request seem to be fine:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?q=demonstration&lat=30.0444&lng=31.2357&distance=1000&min_timestamp=1383253200000&max_timestamp=1385758800000&access_token=9xxx4
```

specifying timestamps with a range of a month, is that an issue?

P.S. Using JQuery 1.9.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the last three 0s in your timestamp and it will work, I just tested this and it works

your timestamp is in miliseconds, it should be in seconds, you have to do time/1000.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?q=demonstration&lat=30.0444&lng=31.2357&distance=1000&min_timestamp=1383253200&max_timestamp=1385758800&access_token=9xxx4
```

Here is a implementation I have done for this API with timestamp change: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

(I dont think there is a 7 day limit, i can go back 30+ days before and get results)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search):

> The time span must not exceed 7 days.

Don't forget that a Unix timestamp is *seconds* since the epoch. So in JS you'd do:

```
Math.round(new Date.getTime() / 1000 );
```

Comment: is it 7 days time frame, or 7 days from current date (now)?

Comment: Because the thing is I get the same error using a correct time frame?!

Comment: does it work with no min and max? Also, they look too big, are you converting from ms to s?

Comment: So here is the situation:

1. The time frame doesn't seem to meter, in fact it works even with older time.

2. My timestamps are not wrong they are simply in milliseconds and it doesn't accept it, so I converted it (like you are mentioning) and now it works fine .

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used the word wrong. A Unix timestamp is always in seconds so if the docs say they're expecting a Unix timestamp (which they do) it should be in seconds.